# How to open proxy channel when endpoint defined in config file?

Tags: .net, wcf

I work on WCF project.

Here is contract:

```
[ServiceContract]
interface IContract
{
    [OperationContract]
    string MethodTest(string s);

    [OperationContract]
    List<hydrants_log_maxtime> GetData(DateTime dateTime);
}
```

And here is how I access to host service end point:

```
        IContract proxy = ChannelFactory<IContract>.CreateChannel(new BasicHttpBinding(),
                                                    new EndpointAddress("http://localhost/HydrantEvents/Hydrant.svc"));

        using (proxy as IDisposable)
        {
            var rows = proxy.GetData(new DateTime(2000, 5, 1));
            var result = proxy.MethodTest("sss");
        }
```

I move the definition of end point on the client to app.config file:

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://localhost/HydrantEvents/Hydrant.svc"
                binding="wsHttpBinding"
                contract="HydrantsEventsConsumer.IContract"/>
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

But when I moved the definition of the end point to the config file I don't know how to open proxy channel to communicate with service host, because I don't have proxy instance it defined in .config file.

How to open proxy channel when endpoint defined in config file?

Comment: Is it possible to just let Visual Studio do the hard work? Right click on references, add Service Reference, put your localhost address in the prompt, and it will create all the config settings with associated code behind that allows you to easily create a client and hit your service methods.

Comment: @TylerStandishMan , Yes I know I want to implement it manually.

Answer (score 0):

You can assign a value to the `name` attribute in the `<endpoint>` section of the config file, and then use the overload of [`ChannelFactory<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms574913%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that takes the name value to create the proxy.

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <client>
    <endpoint address="http://localhost/HydrantEvents/Hydrant.svc"
              binding="wsHttpBinding"
              contract="HydrantsEventsConsumer.IContract"
              name="MyEndpoint" />
  </client>
</system.serviceModel>

IContract proxy = ChannelFactory<IContract>("MyEndpoint").CreateChannel();
```